# CSRF verification failed Django-rest-framework Djoser

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have a project in Django-rest-framework using a react spa based on the youtube tutorial of
Bryan Dunn - Web Development Videos
[here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJRGQoqpRwdfoa9591BcUS6NmMpZcvFsM). I have a problem extending it to a blog app because I keep on getting this error.

[image]

```
#blog/view.py
class BlogListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()


class BlogDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
```

is this a problem on frontend request? perhaps a header that have been missing or something or in the backend? Because I have no problem using it in Postman and the YASG.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know how to do it in class views but if you are using function views , you can use csrf_exempt decorator
'from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt'
And then
@csrf_exemot
def your_function()
......